# Open port to only one external IP address

Tags: networking, security, router, draytek

I am having trouble with unwanted traffic on a certain open port and want to lock the open port so it only allows incoming traffic from One single external IP address. I have had a Google and cant seem to find the solution, only mentions of using an iptable (which I have no experience in).

The router being used is a Draytek Vigor2950.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the answer myself. If it helps anyone else the solution I found was:
http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1368080

```
Yes, but it can't be done only by port forward, firewall is also needed.
Steps are as below:
1. Open http port for internal 192.168.1.2(your internal server)
2. Setup two firewall filter rule.
Filter Set 2 Rule 2(first data filter rule)
Direction: WAN -> LAN
Source IP: Any
Destination IP: 192.168.1.2
Service Type: http
Filter: Block if no further match

Filter Set 2 Rule 3
Direction: WAN -> LAN
Source IP: 202.202.202.202
Destination IP: 192.168.1.2
Service Type: http
Filter: Pass immediately

Then only 202.202.202.202 is allowed to access internal server.
```

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. They tend to go away.